# WebSocket connection to 'wss://test.example.com:8090/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out

Tags: ssl, websocket, apache2, vhosts, ratchet

I am using https and websocket connection for Laravel project. I have setup virtual host like following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.example.com
ServerAdmin test.example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin test.example.com
ServerName test.example.com

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "cert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "privkey.pem"
SSLCertificateChainFile "chain.pem"

SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /wss wss://test.example.com:8090/
ProxyPassReverse /wss wss://test.example.com:8090/

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/laravel/public"
<Directory "/var/www/html/laravel/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But it is showing error in browser:

```
   WebSocket connection to 'wss://test.example.com:8090/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
```

Can you please help us what can be issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. It looks like you try to access directly `wss://test.example.com:8090/` from inside your script which mean it will not go through your Apache proxy which makes the Apache config you provide irrelevant. If you want instead proxy your wss through Apache you should use `wss://test.example.com/wss/` (different port, different path).

Comment: I am using apache webserver, but my concern is even if I do not apply proxy pass settings in my vhosts file then it is also showing the same error, how can I configure my server to make it working?

Comment: Again, it is unclear what you are trying to do in the first place (direct access or via Apache). And the answer depends on what you actually want to do: with direct access there might be some firewall you need to open and you need also be sure that the websocket server is accepting requests from outside in the first place (listen on 0.0.0.0 vs. listen on 127.0.0.1 only). When used with Apache you need to be sure to use the correct URL as I've already explained in my last comment. And, given that you specify `wss://` make sure that your WS server is actually doing `wss://` and not just `ws://`

Comment: Okay, websokcet server is doing well with ws because if remove configuration of ssl(443) then it is working fine with http. Websocket server is also accepting requests from outside. Can I know how can I check that WS server is doing  `wss://` and not just  `ws://`

Comment: I think you are mixing up your websocket server (port 8090) with your Apache as reverse proxy (port 443 and 80). Again - it is still unknown what you are actually want to do - direct access or using Apache.